# LCD pixel streaks or LCD screen damage?

Tags: display, lcd

Do these images indicate stuck pixels or is it damage to the LCD screen itself?   It was squeezed during movement.   There are areas of "dead" pixels but when I touch them it appears the pixels react but go back to their state.

[image: damaged lcd screen]

Comment: The "Liquid" part of the Liquid Crystal Display is damaged, you cannot repair it and should replace it.

Comment: I cannot answer my question due to low reputation, but I wanted to say thank you for your responses.  It sounds like it is what I feared and will reach out to Vizio for support and hopeful warranty replacement.

Answer (score 0):

### The core of the LCD is damaged and it cannot be repaired.

#### What you are seeing is far from a stuck pixel.

A stuck pixel is one single pixel that is stuck. It is visually no more than a speck on the display.

The screenshot you posted is clear far greater damage to the LCD itself. I am not too clear on the exact technical names of all of the layers of the LCD screen, but think of it as a sandwich.

- **Back Layer**: The back layer of the screen is the electronics that make it all work as well as the blacklight that shines through to the front so you can see the images.
- **Middle Layer**: The middle layer is where the visual part of an LCD is. An LCD display is basically an elaborate array of shutters that can vary in transparency and primary RGB colors. This combination of brightness and color levels is what works to create images.
- **Front Layer**: The front of the screen is the protective glass or transparent plastic.
- **Protective Top Layer**: In some cases another layer is placed on top of this all to better protect the underlying LCD screen. Many times when a screen is cracked, the display still works because only this protective outer layer is cracked. Kind like how a smartphone with a “cracked” screen can still be used in many cases despite clearly broken glass.

All layers are secured on top of each other. In your case, this damage is clearly the layers no longer being sealed. Could be glue or whatever they use to sandwich the layers. Could also be they are all melded together. But in your case, that tightly packed “sandwich” was bend or broken and there is no real way for an end use to “fix” a mess like that.

The reason you can see the pixels “react” when you press the damaged areas is because you are simply pushing the layers of the LCD back together. But that is just a curiosity at this point.

Right now that LCD is sadly 100% broken and should be replaced.